# I wanted to change this DataSet code into SqlDataReader code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

This code is actually written in dataset method.
It's worked fine. But I wanted to change it into datareader method.

```
public DataSet SelectTopic(LessionPlanBEL bellp)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = "Select * from lessiontopic where subject=@subject ";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@subject", SqlDbType.Int).Value = bellp.subject;


        da.Fill(ds);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 public DataSet SelectTopic(LessionPlanBEL bellp)
            {
                SqlDataReader dr = new SqlDataReader();
                SqlCommand cmd;
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd =new SqlCommand( "Select * from lessiontopic where subject=@subject ",conn);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject", bellp.subject.ToString());
     dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Thank you for considering my question.We cannot use sqldatareader dr=new sqldatareader. Because it has no public constructor. That means it's designed to be created by another object.object. Pls help me...How do i fix  this error??